# Run conda commands in startup script on GCP preemtible virtual machine

Tags: python, bash, google-cloud-platform, anaconda

I am running a deep learning model on a preemptible google VM. I am using anaconda and TensorFlow to run my code. It works fine when I ssh into the machine and run the python script manually. Given the machine is preemptible I created a cloud scheduler to turn the instance if it's preempted every 15 mins. Now I am working on a startup script to resume the model from the point where it was terminated.

I installed anaconda so that it is accessible to all users and tensorflow in a conda environment with name tf.
Here is my startup script

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -u subhashnerella bash -c 'cd ~/Project;. ./startup.sh'
```

run the startup.sh located in home/Project of user 'subhashnerella'.

Inside startup.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate tf
python start.py
```

Here I activated the conda environment and run start.py to train my model.

The error I got by testing the startup script

```
(base) subhashnerella@instance-1:~$ sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup --debug
startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
startup-script: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./startup.sh: line 2: conda: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./startup.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./startup.sh: line 3: conda: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./startup.sh: line 4: python: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./startup.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./startup.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 127.
startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

It's not able to detect conda commands and python. How do I fix this?

Comment: What OS did you create startup.sh with? I think you have an EOL problem (Unix versus DOS).

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is the os for virtual machine

Comment: What OS did you create the startup.sh with? What EOL setting is your editor using?

Comment: windows machine on notepad++.

Comment: Notepad creates files with Windows DOS line endings. You will need to recreate the file on Linux using VI or similar. DOS is `\r\n`. Linux/Unix/macOS is `\n` for line ending (EOL). That is your problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: One tip. VI can change the file format EOL characters. Look at the command `:set ff=unix`.